# 'di questi tempi' o 'in questi tempi' e perché?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Spesso sento dire 'di questi tempi non ci si può lamentare'.

Sapreste dire perché si usa 'di' piuttosto che 'in'?

Answer (score 10):

Credo che entrambi i modi siano corretti, solo che in genere "in questi tempi" è seguito da una parola che ne connota meglio il significato.

Ad esempio: 
1) "In questi tempi difficili non ci si può lamentare" 
2) "In questi ultimi tempi [..]"

Answer (score 1):

"In" è una preposizione semplice, mentre "di" è una proposizione propria. Non c'è nessun motivo che implica la scelta sia dell'uno che dell'altro modo. In poche parole il significato non cambia. Probabilmente, e correggetemi se sbaglio, "di" è più usato al sud, mentre "in" al nord.

Comment: Che cos'è una “proposizione [o preposizione?] propria”? So che la risposta è di più di un anno fa, ma magari chi la diede ogni tanto capita ancora.